# How to load a .app file into iTunes for Windows?

Tags: windows, itunes

I have an app GotYou.app on my Mac, which seems to be a single file (I know it is not, but appears to be so). And we can just drag and drop it into the iTunes on Mac. But when I copied it into Windows OS for copying that into another iTunes - It appears to be a small file along with a folder. How can I copy this into iTunes so that I can install this into an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement on the script mentioned in Shirkrin's link:
[Building IPA (iPhone Application) Files with Xcode](http://devblog.appmagination.com/2009/11/lorum-ipsum.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not excatly right about the iPhone apps and iTunes.
While you can drag a *.app* into iTunes and install it on your iPhone iTunes will internaly create an *.ipa* from it first.

*ipa's* are the native (single zip-file) distribution format used by all iPhone apps
while stored in your iTunes library.

Have a look at this tutorial to learn how to create an [ipa from within Xcode](http://idotcomllc.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/how-to-build-a-ipa-file-from-xcode/).

You should be able to copy the resulting file to a Windows PC and install it in iTunes.

Hope this helps ;)